# Using functools.partial with default values

Tags: python, partials, functools

## Problem

As the title suggest, I am trying to use `functools.partial` to create a default setting for a callable. However, some of the parameters depend on each other.

## Background

Imagine I have a function `_print_slice(items: list[int], start: int, end: int)` that takes in a `list` and prints items from `start` to `end`.

#### `_print_slice` definition

```
def _print_slice(items: list[int], start: int, end: int) -> None:
    print(items[start:end])
```

I want to make a partial version of this function called `print_list` that prints the entire list, i.e, `start = 0` and `end = len(items)`

#### `print_list` definition

```
def print_list(items: list[int]) -> None:
    _print_slice(items=items, start=0, end=len(items))
```

notice that `print_list` is just a wrapper around `_print_slice`. If I am not mistaken, this would be a perfect use case for `functools.partial`, however, I am not sure to use use partial to accomplish this given that `end = len(items)`, please help.

## Disclaimer

This is a very simplified version of the problem to highlight what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: To answer the literal question you asked: use `None` as the value that you pass for the `end` parameter, instead of `len(items)`.  I have no idea if that answers the real question, that you didn't actually ask, but maybe it gives you an idea.  There's certainly no way to use a non-constant value with `partial()`.

Comment: It's trivial to write a wrapper function that calls another function with computed arguments anyway. Definitely not worth re-inventing `partial`. e.g. `def print_list(items: list[int]) -> None:
    _print_slice(items, 0, len(items))`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for `functools.partial`. It cannot perform the kind of dependent argument computation you want. `functools.partial` is designed to fix argument values, not to compute them from other argument values.

(Due to the way slicing handles `None` endpoints, `partial(_print_slice, start=None, end=None)` would have the behavior you want, but that's something the list slicing implementation would handle, not something `partial` handles - it wouldn't generalize to other uses of `partial`. Also, it violates the `_print_slice` argument annotations.)